# Fullcalendar v5 is not showing up in JHipster project

Tags: typescript, jhipster, angular10, fullcalendar-5

Fullcalendar v5 is not showing up in JHipster project. I've searched all other questions about this problem but couldn't find an answer for this.

Here is part of my code:

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "10.1.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.4.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.7.1",
```

webpack.dev.js

```
,
        {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: [
              'handlebars-loader', // handlebars loader expects raw resource string
              'extract-loader',
              'css-loader',
            ],
         }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  interactionPlugin
])

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FullCalendarModule
  ],
```

component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarOptions, DateSelectArg, EventClickArg, EventApi } from '@fullcalendar/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-component',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
})
export class Component {

  calendarVisible = true;
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
   
  };

}
```

component.html

```
<div class='demo-app'>
  <div class='demo-app-main'>
    <full-calendar [options]='calendarOptions'></full-calendar>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does someone has any idea why full-calendar is now showing? There is no error, just empty page.
Thanks.

Comment: If there's no error and it's not showing it 's probably due to missing CSS.From their doc it seems you did not configure webpack css-loader

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also tried with and without import of css in vendor.scss but it makes no difference. But in documentation for fullcalendar version 5 stands, that css are automatically imported, so I'm confused should there be import of css or not?

Comment: I don't know,  I always use PrimeNG for my Angular apps and they already integrate FullCalendar so everything is simpler.

Comment: I did now npm install --save-dev css-loader, but calendar is still not shown.

Comment: css-loader is already included in your JHipster app, so basically you did nothing :) What you need is to check its webpack configuration is compatible with what FullCalendar documents.